# Can't format microSD card

Tags: formatting, micro-sd-card, write-protect

I am trying to format a microSD card. I have tried (unsuccessfully) erasing the memory from the Settings menu on an Android device at my disposal and now I have plugged the USB and givin it a go from Ubuntu (I can't use Windows).

Every time I try to format (or manually delete) data, every file and directory seem to stay put.

I thought it could be a microSD card corruption problem, but as I type

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdc
```

The only warning message I get is:

```
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
```

Then I issue the command one more time and the check is fine.

I've realized that the microSD card is on write-lock. Here it is what I have tried so far with no results whatsoever:

- put the microSD into an adapter and mechanically slide the the switch to unlock;
- manually changed permissions as root;
- `gksudo nautilus` in order to remove files;
- `fsck.vfat -v -a -w /dev/sdc` to try format the card;
- `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdc` to erase the partition

I am out of ideas, can anyone please help me try to sort this out?

**Update**: Running `gparted` I get this new piece of information

```
plain floppy: device "/dev/sdc" busy (Resource temporarily unavailable):
Cannot initialize '::'
mlabel: Cannot initialize drive
```

Comment: This guy looks like he got it: http://superuser.com/questions/527657/how-do-you-format-a-2-gb-sd-card-to-fat32-preferably-with-disk-utility

Comment: @ejbytes thanks for your input, unfortunately the other OP seems to be on a mac and apparently diskutil is not available on Ubuntu.

Comment: gnome-disks? I used Linux in different "flavours" and I know they all have different syntax, which is why Linux was so difficult for me to learn. Sorry, haven't used it since I stopped programming at a particular University which made it mandatory. Try narrowing your search in Google, you might get lucky.

Comment: @ejbytes no luck there either, it seems like it has been formatted but if I unmount and re-mount the card all the stuff is still there.

Comment: That's a sure sign the firmware write protection has triggered. Give up now. Bin it.